# visual basic 2010 error when compiling......No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Why this Error message displays?

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

```
Private Sub frmAddbooknew_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LIBRARY_SYSTEMDataSet3.LIBRARY__BOOK_Query' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.LIBRARY__BOOK_QueryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LIBRARY_SYSTEMDataSet3.LIBRARY__BOOK_Query)
End Sub
```

Comment: If `LIBRARY__BOOK_QueryTableAdapter` is a table-adapater and `LIBRARY_SYSTEMDataSet3.LIBRARY__BOOK_Query` is a typed `DataTable` that should compile and work. Is it really the line that causes the error? Can you show the declaration of the adapter and the dataset?

Comment: Does the stacktrace in your error message point to that line?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you're not sure about variables you're sending to a function you can put a breakpoint before its summoned and then use the "immediate" console window to check every variable or behavior.
Just go to immediate and write

`?variable_name`
Then press enter, this will execute and will display at runtime that variable or action, this way you can check everything without having to use labels and textboxes.

This way you can check constants or system functions like datetime() while you're designing your program